# how do i track a users activity online

Tags: plugins, android-activity, monitoring, interaction, tracker

We are building a system that seeks to calculate and score the value of information and users of information - based on the interaction between the two. 
To do this, we need to track and measure these interactions. We are working on different ways - from connecting your social services and monitoring them (hard to scale and requires very patient users happy to connect services) to explicit tracking having a bookmarklet ala digg that user can trigger whenever she is on a piece of information (basically, content) that she wants included in her score.

What we'd really like is a tool that could do something like;
monitor all activity of a person across all networks (read, watch, comment, post, tweet, author, etc) and actively sit in the users browser and 'listen and report' back to HQ anytime a defined activity takes place.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor the Social network activities for ex. Facebook, you need to take the authentication from the user like read/friends list etc. and fetch the updates from facebook with in specific interval of time and report same to HQ.
 The same thing you need to report for other networking sites.
Each network sites may have different APIs you need collect and take the permission of the users (like signin).

Hope it helps.